# Pipeline CI/CD actions only on changed files

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to create a `gitlab ci/cd pipeline` able to upload on Amazon S3 only the edited files. It is a possible thing? If yes, how can I edit my current `.gitlab-ci.yml` so only the changed files are uploade to `ASW S3`:

```
stages:
- deploy-s3-bucket

deploy_s3_bucket:
  stage: deploy-s3-bucket
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - aws configure set region us-east-2
    - aws s3 cp . s3://$S3_BUCKET/ --recursive --exclude ".git/*" --exclude ".gitlab-ci.yml" --exclude ".gitignore"
  only: ['master']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **AWS Sync** command will help you to achieve your task.

Use below command, instead of your **aws cp** command:

> **aws s3 sync . s3://$S3_BUCKET/ --exclude ".git/*" --exclude ".gitlab-ci.yml" --exclude ".gitignore"**

it will recursively copy new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. Also, It will only create folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws s3 sync site/ s3://<bucket_name>` under script. Using the sync command copies missing or outdated files.

View more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-sync

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the proposed solutions don't work.
s3 sync compares the source and destination by 2 criteria:

- Modification date
- Size

When you run the job in CICD, it does a "git pull" in the background with your revision and the modification date of all the files is updated, and thus - it's uploading all the files each time you run it.
You can omit the check on the modification date by using the "--size-only" flag, but it will not work in situations when the size of the modified file is unchanged.

I solved it by creating a helper script that uses the following command in order to get the list of updated files:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
```

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

FILES=()
for i in $( git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | grep cloudformation | grep ".json" | sed 's#aws-tools/cloudformation/##g'); do # CHANGEIT
    FILES+=( "$i" )
done
echo "${FILES[@]}"

CMDS=()
for i in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    CMDS+=("--include=$i""*")
done
echo "${CMDS[@]}"

echo "${CMDS[@]}" | xargs aws s3 sync aws-tools/cloudformation/ s3://bucket-name/ --delete --exclude "*" # CHANGEIT
```

You need to change the lines containing "CHANGEIT". In my case, it syncs the folder aws-tools/cloudformation/ to s3://bucket-name/, so there shouldn't be any "aws-tools/cloudformation" folder inside the bucket. Also, I'm uploading just the .json files.

I took inspiration from:
https://www.lambrospetrou.com/articles/aws-s3-sync-git-status/